# Difference between drupal-composer vs drupal-recommended

Tags: 9

drupal-composer/drupal-project
drupal/recommended-project

Which one is the best option to choose & why? on Drupal 9

1. composer create-project drupal/recommended-project:

/vendor: 4485 files, ~21 Mo

2. composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:

/vendor: 12624 files, ~62 Mo

Answer (score 7):

The important difference is that you should use *drupal/recommended-project* as it is recommended and officially supported. *drupal-composer/drupal-project* is outdated for Drupal 8+ and should only be used for Drupal 7.

From the [Using Composer to Install Drupal and Manage Dependencies](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/manage-dependencies) documentation on d.o:

> As of the release of Drupal 8.8.0 - the recommend composer template changed from drupal-composer/drupal-project to the officially supported: [drupal/recommended-project](https://github.com/drupal/recommended-project)
>
> For Drupal 9, use the composer template at drupal/recommended-project. This template ensures Drupal Core dependencies are the exact same version as the official Drupal release.
>
> For Drupal 7, use [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/tree/7.x).

While alluded to in the quote from the d.o documentation, I think it's worth calling out: a key difference between the two templates is that *drupal/recommended-project* includes a `composer.lock` file which "ensures Drupal Core dependencies are the exact same version as the official Drupal release."

Comment: Yeah thanks Sonfd. but drupal composer available for Drupal 9. https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project

Comment: @ThirstySix `drupal-composer` can be used with Drupal 9 still but it is effectively obsolete, as stated in this answer.  The new supported way is `recommended-project`, and the recommendation to use it is right there in the name.

Comment: If you're asking why that repository has a 9.x version, that's something you're going to have to ask the maintainers in that project's issue queue. As stated, as of Drupal 8.8 (released 12/4/2019), _drupal/recommended-project_ is the recommended and officially supported template.

Comment: Thank you PatrickKenny & sonfd